# Add streaming Listener to Stop after first Iteration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to know how implement Streaming Listener to Stop a Streaming application.

I need a small example with Dependencies, imports and implement Codes.

Similar to [detecting connection lost in spark streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272141)

Can you Help me?

Comment: You need to call `streamingContext.stop()` when your first iteration is over. 
To check whether the first iteration is over or not, you should use `StreamingListener` interface. You can create a custom `streamingListener` object and use in a context by `StreamingContext.addStreamingListener(<custom streaminglistener object>)`

Comment: I don't have any code, so just given an idea on this.